# Creating DataFrame of groups by pixel values in Python (number, size, etc.)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data (simple representation of black particles on a white filter):

```
data = [
    [0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0],
    [0, 255, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0, ],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0],
    [0, 255, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 0, 0]
]
```

And I have counted the number of particles (groups) and assigned them each a number using the following code:

```
arr = np.array(data)
groups, group_count = measure.label(arr > 0, return_num = True, connectivity = 1)
print('Groups: \n', groups)
```

With the **Output**:

```
Groups: 
 [[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 2 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 3 3 0 0 4 0 0]
 [0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 4 0 0]]
```

I then have four (4) particles (groups) of different sizes.

I am looking to create a DataFrame representing each particle. Like this:

[image: DataFrame of particles (groups)]

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a more elegant approach, but here is what I have come up with:

```py
import pandas as pd
customDict = {}
for group in groups:
  for value in group:
    if str(value) not in customDict:
      customDict[str(value)] = [0]
    customDict[str(value)][0] += 1
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(customDict, orient="index").reset_index()
df.rename(columns={"index": "particle #", 0: "size"}, inplace=True)
df.drop(0, inplace=True)
df
```

##### Output

|  | particle # | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts=True`:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.c_[np.unique(groups, return_counts=True)],
                   columns=['Particle #', 'Size'])
        .loc[lambda d: d['Particle #'].ne(0)] # only to filter out the 0s
     )
```

or, different syntax:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(['Particle #', 'Size'],
                            np.unique(groups, return_counts=True))))
        .loc[lambda d: d['Particle #'].ne(0)] # only to filter out the 0s
     )
```

output:

```
   Particle #  Size
1           1    10
2           2     1
3           3     3
4           4     4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Counter** from the collection library:

```
import collections
import pandas as pd

groups = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
          [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0]]

counter = collections.Counter(groups[0])
for i in range(1,len(groups)):
    counter = counter + collections.Counter(groups[i]) 
    
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(counter, orient='index', columns=["Size"]).drop(0)

>>> df
   Size
1    10
2     1
3     3
4     4
```